# How to properly handle constant stream of data in RecyclerView using MVVM?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-mvvm

My project has been written in MVP pattern.
Each element of RecyclerView is a custom view. Each custom view has **presenter** inside which is responsible for listening on data from stream and setting received value in custom view. Stream is sending new data every 4s.
Model which stream is sending is a **list of objects**:

```
FancyStreamValue(val id: Int, val value: String)
```

Each tile in RecyclerView has fixed id which is the same like id from FancyStreamValue so each presenter is getting value from stream under his id.

[image: Picture describes how recycler view looks]

I would like to make refactor to MVVM pattern with LiveData. As I know custom view shouldn't have ViewModel inside. What is the best way to implement this right know ?
So far I have tried with one ViewModel which is fetching whole list of values from stream and setting recycler view adapter via

```
fancyStreamAdapter.submitList(streamValuesList)
```

**I noticed that recyclerview list is not scrolling 100% smooth, just jams from time to time when new data arrives from stream with new values**

RecyclerView is also **flickering** and I'm not sure if it is **efficient** to refresh whole list all the time every 4s ?
Advice please :)
Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: `As I know custom view shouldn't have ViewModel` - incorrect.  If you like every single widget on a screen can have a view model - 1:n relationship.  Most Android MVVM tutorials will use a monlithic View Model as the dumping ground for and entire screen UI interactions which is fine for toy app tutorials -however you will soon come into issues if you try and scale or reuse items as logic will end up being copy/pasted.  Consider the pattern in more general terms and principles like encapulsation - is it good encapsulation to have a monolithiic view model know about an entire complex ui screen.

Comment: @MarkKeen But ViewModel has been intended to work with Activity/Fragment lifecycle, I'm not sure if it will be working good with custom view and LiveData, do you have any useful articles ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just replace your current presenter with a view model - it seems you are swapping one architectural pattern for a another ...  if you are fixated on providing it a Activity/Fragment then just provide a reference to the `LifecycleOwner`

Comment: How does your `fancyStreamAdapter` look like? Does `DiffUtil` set up properly?

Comment: @LinLin RecyclerView item is flickering when value will change

Comment: @piczaj In the question, you mentioned that it refreshes like every 4s. Seems like other parts of the code (not related to RecyclerView) has some kind of looping or reloading.

Comment: @LinLin source of data for RecyclerView is a stream like websocket

Comment: Probably the socket emit continuously or something. You can use `liveData.distinctUntilChanged()` in order to emit only dataset is different.